# Searching text with NEAR regex

Tags: r, regex

I have a vector containing text, broken up, like the following:

```
words =  c("Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the", "printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industrys 
            standard dummy text ever since the 1500s", "when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to 
            make a type specimen book.", "It has survived not only five ,centuries, but also the leap into electronic")
```

I am using the following regex to find where the words "dummy" and "text" appear within 6 words of each other:

```
grep("\b(?:dummy\\W+(?:\\w+\\W+){1,6}?text|text\\W+(?:\\w+\\W+){1,6}?dummy)\b", words)
```

However its returning 0 despite there being 'dummy text' within the first index.

Any idea where I am going wrong?

Comment: `\b` must be `\\b`

Comment: grep("\\b(?:dummy\\W+(?:\\w+\\W+){1,6}?text|text\\W+(?:\\w+\\W+){1,6}?dummy)\\b", words) is still returning 0?

Comment: So, you want to allow **zero** words between them, too? https://regex101.com/r/XXomAw/1 - replace `{1,6}?` with `{0,6}`

Comment: I am an idiot. Thank you. Sorry I thought 1 meant next to each other. Good spot. Ty!

Comment: Very helpful, thank you Wiktor!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `\b` in `"\b"` matches a backspace char, you need to double escape the `\b`, `\\b`, to make it match a word boundary.

After fixing the typo, you need to pay attention to the *limiting quantifiers*. `{1,6}?` is a *lazy* quantifier matching one to six occurrences (as few as possible, but still as many as necessary to find a valid match) of the modified subpattern. It means there must be *at least one* word between `dummy` and `text`.

So, you need to use

```r
pattern <- "\\b(?:dummy\\W+(?:\\w+\\W+){0,6}text|text\\W+(?:\\w+\\W+){0,6}dummy)\\b"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/XXomAw/1/).

**Details**

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(?:` - start of a non-capturing group

  - `dummy` - a `dummy` word
  - `\W+` - one or more non-word chars
  - `(?:\w+\W+){0,6}` - zero to six occurrences of one or more word chars followed with one or more non-word chars
  - `text` - a `text` word
- `|` - or

  - `text` - a `text` word
  - `\W+` - one or more non-word chars
  - `(?:\w+\W+){0,6}` - zero to six occurrences of one or more word chars followed with one or more non-word chars
  - `dummy` - a `dummy` word
- `)` - end of the non-capturing group
- `\b` - a word boundary

Comment: Thank you for your descriptive response. Very helpful and informative for myself and anyone else looking for how to search R text for words within a certain proximity!