# String matching with NEAR regex and multiple terms

Tags: r, regex, string-matching, grepl

I have a vector containing some strings, like the following:

```
test_strings <- c("this string referring to dummy text should be matched", 
                  "this string referring to an example of code should be matched",
                  "this string referring to texts which are kind of dumb should be matched",
                  "this string referring to an example, but with a really long gap before mentioning a word such as 'text' should not be matched")
```

I have two lists of search terms:

```
list_a <- c("dummy", "dumb", "example", "examples")
list_b <- c("text", "texts", "script", "scripts", "code")
```

I would like to return matches where there is some combination of a string from list_a and a string from list_b, with these strings appearing within 10 words of each other (i.e. elements 1-3 of test_strings).

Based on the helpful answers to this question: [R - Searching text with NEAR regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65237757/r-searching-text-with-near-regex), I was able to implement the 'NEAR' function, but my code fails to return the correct matches once I include multiple terms, some of which are substrings.

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
regex_string <- "\\b(?:(dum|example)\\W+(?:\\w+\\W+){0,10}?(text|script|code)|(text|script|code)\\W+(?:\\w+\\W+){0,10}?(dum|example))\\b"

test_results <- test_strings[grepl(regex_string,test_strings, ignore.case=TRUE)]

test_results
```

Only returns strings with an exact match - i.e. "this string referring to an example of code should be matched"

```
regex_string <- "\\b(?:(dum.*|example.*)\\W+(?:\\w+\\W+){0,10}?(text.*|script.*|code)|(text.*|script.*|code)\\W+(?:\\w+\\W+){0,10}?(dum.*|example.*))\\b"

test_results <- test_strings[grepl(regex_string,test_strings, ignore.case=TRUE)]

test_results
```

Allows me to match substrings so that "this string referring to dummy text should be matched", "this string referring to an example of code should be matched" and "this string referring to texts which are kind of dumb should be matched" are returned.

However, "this string referring to an example, but with a really long gap before mentioning a word such as 'text' should not be matched" is also returned, I guess as the inclusion of ".*" is somehow invalidating the 0-10 word restriction.

Any ideas on how I could fix this?

Comment: Have you tried replacing the `(dum.*|example.*)` part with the four word alternation `(dummy|dumb|example|examples)`? The 2 uses of `.*` will, as you suspect, match lots of characters that you do not want to be matched.

Comment: Yes, you're right, this does work, but for my actual code I have a lot more potential strings and wanted to make sure i caught all of them without explicitly specifying. Like maybe if there was a way to restrict the characters returned by .* to just within the word.

Comment: Use character classes.  Perhaps use `[a-z@_]*` or whatever characters apply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really need a regex, then this one should work:

```
regex_string <- r"(\b(?:dum|example)\w*(?:\W+\w+){0,10}\W+(?:text\w*|script\w*|code)\b|\b(?:text\w*|script\w*|code)(?:\W+\w+){0,10}\W+(?:dum|example)\w*\b)"
```

`.*` didn't work because it's greedy, also variable length matching of anything with no strict boundaries isn't usually a good idea.

Explantation:

- `\b(?:dum|example)\w*` - match any sort of word starting with `dum` or `example`
- `(?:\W+\w+){0,10}\W+` - match up to 10 words followed by some non-word character(s)
- `(?:text\w*|script\w*|code)\b` - match a word beginning by `text`/`script` or just `code`
  The alternative is similar but with positions swapped. just like in your attempt.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/3xP088/1) with further explantations.

Using text-based solutions for such tasks is often more optimal though.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have to use regex?

```r
sapply(
  strsplit(test_strings, "[^A-Za-z]+"),
  function(st) {
    tmp <- outer(na.omit(match(list_b, st)), na.omit(match(list_a, st)), `-`)
    any(tmp > 0 & tmp <= 10)
  })
# [1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

This indicates that the first three of `test_strings` have something from `list_b` occurring 10 words or fewer from something from `list_a`, and the fourth element does not.